# Ghostscript gsdll32.dll give assembly is not install on your system

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, wcf

I have copy gsdll32.dll in bin folder and it correctly select but give the below error.

Unable to load DLL 'gsdll32.dll': The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

How to install this gsdll32.dll file.

Comment: Check this blog post: https://aspsqltutorials.blogspot.com/2015/09/unable-to-load-dll-gsdll32dll-specified.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's work. And found that the it's not .net based library (It was created in "c") so it will not directly load from bin folder or any reference.